# wp8 : how to insert map into PanoramaItem HeaderTemplate

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, dictionary, panorama-control

I'm trying to insert map control into PanoramaItem Header in my App :

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Orientation="Horizontal" Width="480">

            <phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="155" Width="478" Margin="-23,0,0,0">
                        <!-- Map -->
                        <maps:Map x:Name="StationsMapOverview"
                                  Visibility="{Binding IsDataLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                  Height="115" 
                                  Margin="0,-34,0,0"
                                  ZoomLevel="10"
                                  Center="{Binding UserGeoCoordinate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  CartographicMode="Road"
                                  ColorMode="Light"
                                  PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True"
                                  LandmarksEnabled="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>

            <!-- Stations list -->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListNearbyItems" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding StationItems}" Margin="0,-38,0,0" Height="480">
...
```

The result is good and my map appears well.
But in the behind code, I have the following error:

```
name 'StationsMapOverview' does not exist in the current context
```

(`Datacontext` is set by `ViewModelLocator` class and work fine for others pages).
And 'center' option binding is not working.

So my question is, is that someone has tried to integrate a map into `PanoramaItem Header` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass `DataContext` inside header template add:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header={Binding} x:Name="panorama"
```

You can't access an object in template by name. Use code below to find element by name:

```
private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement, string name) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
    if (count == 0)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

        if (child != null && child is FrameworkElement && (child as FrameworkElement).Name.Equals(name))
        {
            return (T)child;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child, name);
            if (result != null)
                return result;

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then call:

```
Map map = FindElementInVisualTree<Map>(panorama, "StationsMapOverview");
```