# using web browser with other layout in visual studio 2012 for windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to use the web browser along with a header block in Windows phone 8. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I played along and found that we can put browser on top and add items below that,but i need a header. I am new in Windows mobile programming, please help.
I have tried using Stackpanel and grid layouts, but got no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tab like feel is what you are focusing at visually, pivot control would suffice your needs.
Panorama however will not be appropriate in this case. 
Pivot has its own pivot items and a title field wherein you can get what you desire.
Thanks

Comment: I would also like to add a note-
In case you place a browser control on a layout that itself has some gesture recognition facility, (e.g. pivot, which has a left and right swipe), this may cause problems with swipes on your browser control. That is, when you wish to swipe on something in a browser, the swipe may be forwarded to the pivot and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot or panorama.

Pivot:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941103(v=vs.105).aspx

Panorama:
[wp8 : how to insert map into PanoramaItem HeaderTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631112/wp8-how-to-insert-map-into-panoramaitem-headertemplate)

Hope this helps.